# JavaScript создание карты из тайлов, загрузка и мерцание изображений на холсте

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр, 2d

Я столкнулся с проблемой мерцания элементов на холсте, использую requestAnimationFrame. Как этого можно избежать? setInterval тоже самое выходит. Вопрос по поводу загрузки и выводу изображений на холст, я делаю так.

```
        var tiles = {'x': {'tile': './tiles/tile1.png'}, ' ': {'tile': ''}};

        var map = [
            ['x', 'x', 'x'],
            ['x', ' ', 'x'],
            ['x', 'x', 'x']
        ];

        for (var row = 0; row < map.length; row++) {
            for (var col = 0; col < map[row].length; col++) {

                xpos = col * twidth;
                ypos = row * theight;

                var img1 = new Image(); 
                img1.src = tiles[map[row][col]]['tile'];
                ctx.drawImage(img1, xpos, ypos, twidth, theight);
            }
        }
```

Где правильно вызывать конструктор класса Image? Подскажите как вообще реализуются такие генераторы карт, где спрайтов может быть много, и они разные? Делаю карту больше раз в 10 она вообще тормозит при загрузке.

Comment: наверное, было бы лучше, если бы до момента начала отрисовки карты, все картинки были загружены. У вас же, картинки подгружаются в процессе отрисовки. При чем, скорее всего, при первой отрисовке, картинки не прорисовываются

Comment: Да я именно так и решил вопрос.